# How do I convert xml with depth (and info in attributes) to csv, each line representing a first-level tag in the xml?

Tags: xml, xslt, csv, converters

I have an xml file with this structure:

```
<a>
    <b attribute="54" name="Bob" ... >
        <c name="Foo" stuff="89" attr="First line&#xA;Second line" ... />
        <c name="Bar" stuff="23" attr="Blahs" ... />
        ...
    </b>
    ...
</a>
```

I would like to get this data in a csv file looking something like:

```
b_attribute, b_name, ... , c1_name, c1_stuff, c1_attr ... , c2_name, c2_stuff, c2_attr ... 
"54", "Bob", ..., "Foo", "89", "First line&#xA;Second line", ..., "Bar", "23", "Blahs", ...
```

some of the tags' values may contain html commas and quotes.

Comment: Are all of the top-level values guaranteed to have the same set of fields?  In other words, could the first row of the CSV (with the header names) be determined just by looking at the first row? And your example XML is invalid.  You can't have an attribute without quotes (single or double) around it: `attribute=54`.  How would you like to preserve the line breaks?

Comment: @JLRishe : All `b` tags have the same set of attributes. The same goes for `c`. I would like to preserve the line breaks.

Comment: I don't know a lot about CSV, but are you saying that line breaks should actually be reproduced as line breaks in the output? And how should quotes and other characters in the values be escaped?  The sample output has no quotes around the 54, but is that a requirement?

Comment: @JLRishe The linebreaks should not appear as such in the CSV (I've fixed the example above so that it reflects this). Escaping the characters with html is what I think is ideal.

Comment: Which characters?  Please provide a complete list of what needs to be escaped.

Comment: The characters are comma (`,`), double quotes (`"`) and linebreaks, because they can really mess up the csv format (which uses them as separators.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How's this:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl"
                xmlns:templates="csv-templates" xmlns:values="csv-values"
>
  <templates:header />
  <templates:value />
  <xsl:variable name="header" select="document('')//templates:header" />
  <xsl:variable name="value" select="document('')//templates:value" />

  <values:substitutions>
    <sub from="&quot;" to="&quot;quot;" />
    <sub from="," to="&quot;#x2C;" />
    <sub from="&#xA;" to="&amp;#xA;" />
  </values:substitutions>
  <xsl:variable name="substitutions" select="document('')//values:substitutions" />

  <xsl:output method="text" />

  <xsl:template match="text()" />

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="*/*" mode="headers">
      <xsl:sort data-type="number" select="count(*)" order="descending"/>
    </xsl:apply-templates>
    <xsl:variable name="headerCount">
      <xsl:apply-templates select="*/*" mode="countAttributes">
        <xsl:sort data-type="number" select="count(*)" order="descending"/>
      </xsl:apply-templates>
    </xsl:variable>

    <xsl:apply-templates select="*/*">
      <xsl:with-param name="headerCount" select="$headerCount" />
    </xsl:apply-templates>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="/*/*">
    <xsl:param name="headerCount" />
    <xsl:text>&#xA;</xsl:text>
    <xsl:call-template name="CommaList">
      <xsl:with-param name="items" select=".//@*"/>
      <xsl:with-param name="type" select="$value" />
      <xsl:with-param name="minCount" select="$headerCount" />
    </xsl:call-template>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="/*/*" mode="headers">
    <xsl:if test="position() = 1">
      <xsl:call-template name="CommaList">
        <xsl:with-param name="items" select=".//@*"/>
        <xsl:with-param name="type" select="$header" />
      </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:if>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="/*/*" mode="countAttributes">
    <xsl:if test="position() = 1">
      <xsl:value-of select="count(.//@*)"/>
    </xsl:if>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="templates:header" priority="2">
    <xsl:param name="item" />
    <xsl:variable name="index">
      <xsl:if test="count($item/ancestor::*) > 2">
        <xsl:value-of select="count($item/../preceding-sibling::*) + 1"/>
      </xsl:if>
    </xsl:variable>
    <xsl:value-of select="concat(local-name($item/..), $index, '_', local-name($item))"/>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="templates:value" priority="2">
    <xsl:param name="item" />
    <xsl:if test="normalize-space($item)">
      <xsl:text>"</xsl:text>
      <xsl:call-template name="escape">
        <xsl:with-param name="value" select="$item" />
      </xsl:call-template>
      <xsl:text>"</xsl:text>
    </xsl:if>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template name="CommaList">
    <xsl:param name="items" />
    <xsl:param name="type" />
    <xsl:param name="minCount" select="0" />

    <xsl:apply-templates select="$type">
      <xsl:with-param name="item" select="$items[1]" />
    </xsl:apply-templates>

    <xsl:variable name="remainder" select="$items[position() > 1]" />
    <xsl:if test="$remainder or $minCount > 1">
      <xsl:text>, </xsl:text>
      <xsl:call-template name="CommaList">
        <xsl:with-param name="items" select="$remainder" />
        <xsl:with-param name="type" select="$type" />
        <xsl:with-param name="minCount" select="$minCount - 1" />
      </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:if>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template name="escape">
    <xsl:param name="value"/>

    <xsl:variable name="foundToEscape" select="$substitutions/sub[contains($value, @from)]" />

    <xsl:choose>
      <xsl:when test="$foundToEscape">
        <xsl:call-template name="escape">
          <xsl:with-param name="value" select="substring-before($value, $foundToEscape/@from)" />
        </xsl:call-template>
        <xsl:value-of select="$foundToEscape/@to"/>
        <xsl:call-template name="escape">
          <xsl:with-param name="value" select="substring-after($value, $foundToEscape/@from)" />
        </xsl:call-template>
      </xsl:when>
      <xsl:otherwise>
        <xsl:value-of select="$value"/>
      </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Additional substitution rules can be added by adding additional `<sub>` elements to the `<values:substitutions>` element.

Comment: Wow! That's almost exactly what I was hoping for. Is it possible to account for more than one `c` element within each `b` element?

Comment: How would that work? More than one column header with the same name? Will all `b`s have the same number of `c`s?

Comment: I've updated the example, and yes, there is an arbitrary number of `c`s.

Comment: Updated my answer. Is the XML guaranteed to have only `c`s under the `b`s and nothing deeper than the `c`s?

Comment: Good. But the first row is still showing repeated values, while they should be unique. The `c_name` attribute should have different "column headers" like `..., c1_name, ... c2_name, ...`.

Comment: Oh, and yes, maximum depth is `c`.

Comment: It appears as `..., c1_name, ... c1_name, ...`, but they should be different. Is that possible? (I can just manually edit them if not.)

Comment: My mistake.  Should be fixed now.

Comment: OK, that about fixed it, I think. I might have to fidget a bit with the script to get what the application I'm importing the data into calls "valid CSV", but this certainly does the trick that I couldn't do my self.
Good job, and thank you SO much.

Comment: Oh, the reason I got "invalid CSV" was because there were supposed to be the same number of commas on each line.

Comment: Posted a possible solution to the missing commas issue.

Comment: No, there was an error in my application - this is still valid csv, I believe. Again: Nice work!

Comment: Ok, well if you would like to suppress the transform from adding the extra commas, you can just remove this line: `<xsl:with-param name="minCount" select="$headerCount" />`